# Binding example

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, binding

I have been trying for weeks to find a decent article that explains WPF Binding simply and with a working example that actually explains what is happening. Yes there are lots of examples out there but lots of those refer to older versions of everything involved.

I am trying to write an application, that is not web based, uses WPF and VB on VS2012.

In this bit of code i am updating a screen field directly, but i want to learn how to update a variable in memory and it update on the screen automatically, how do i get from here to there - In stages with explanations

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow" 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        Title="Test Bind" 
        Height="299" Width="500" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" LastChildFill="False" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="64">
            <Button Content="Button" Height="64" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click" />
            <TextBox Height="64" Width="120" Text="TextBox1" x:Name="clickcount" />
            <TextBox Height="64" Width="120"  x:Name="textBox2" Text="{Binding Test, Mode=Default}" />
        </DockPanel>
    </DockPanel>

</Window>

Class MainWindow
  Public Shared clcount As Integer = 0

  Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    clcount = clcount + 1
    Me.clickcount.Text = clcount.ToString
  End Sub    
End Class
```

Comment: To answer your question in the title.  VB.NET is rapidly declining in popularity.

Comment: Once you learn C#, you quickly forget the VB.Net syntax, to the point where you can't stand it anymore. I have a big trouble trying to read VB.Net now, my mind completely rejects it.

Comment: @HighCore: exaggerating is an art ...

Comment: What like? "I told you a million times, not to exaggerate!"

Comment: Jeffery & HighCore - Not very Helpful! I was a traditional programmer in languages such as Pascal, various flavours of Basic and various Assemblers but never C and certainly not OO.